# How to exclude parameters in Shiny bookmarking?

Tags: r, shiny

I am creating a dashboard and I would like to exclude some parameters from bookmarking.

Here's a MWE:

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- function(request) {
    fluidPage(

        # Application title
        titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

        # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                sliderInput("bins",
                            "Number of bins:",
                            min = 1,
                            max = 50,
                            value = 30),
                selectInput(
                    "y",
                    "Year:",
                    choices = 1990:2000,
                    selected = 1990,
                    selectize = TRUE
                )
            ),

            # Show a plot of the generated distribution
            mainPanel(
                plotOutput("distPlot")
            )
        )
    )
}

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        x    <- faithful[, 2]
        bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

        # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
        hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
    })

    observe({
        # Trigger this observer every time an input changes
        # strip shiny related URL parameters
        grep("selectized", reactiveValuesToList(input), value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)
        session$doBookmark()
    })

    onBookmarked(function(url) {
        updateQueryString(url)
    })
}

# Run the application 
enableBookmarking("url")
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It works and returns this valid (and editable) URL 
`http://127.0.0.1:7449/?_inputs_&bins=30&y="1996"&y-selectized=""`

I would like to ignore the "selectized" parameter and exclude it from bookmarking, or at least to remove it from the URL provided it doesn't affect anything at all. I cannot figure out why `grep` is not working here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setBookmarkExclude()` within your server function (then `grep()` is no longer needed):

```r
setBookmarkExclude("y-selectized")
```